# Inequality with an indeterminate form

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x\in\big[-\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{b}\big]^2$ and $y\in U(r)=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^2;\,\|z\|=r\}$ with $r>0$ and $b\geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{r}$ fixed. I'm not able to prove the following inequality: $$\int_{U(r)}\bigg(\frac{\sin(b(x_1-y_1))}{x_1-y_1}\bigg)^2\bigg(\frac{\sin(b(x_2-y_2))}{x_2-y_2}\bigg)^2\,d\sigma(y)\leq Cb^4\frac{1}{b}=Cb^3,$$

with $C>0$ a constant and $d\sigma(y)$ an element of surface area.

My problem is to deal with the points $x,y$ that have an equal coordinate. I understand that, in this case, the $\sin(\cdot)$ is the numerator fixes the $0$ in the denominator.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your notation regarding $x,y,x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$. I can tell you that a main idea is that since $\sin(\theta)\leq \theta$, you will have
$$
LHS\leq b^4 \int_{U(r)}\,\mathrm{d}\sigma(y)
$$
after canceling the $(x_1-y_1)$ and $(x_2-y_2)$ terms.

Comment: The notation is $x=(x_1,x_2), y=(y_1,y_2)$. Nevertheless this estimate is too rough. I would like to prove the one in the statement.

Comment: I do not think the estimate is too rough. Since $\sin(\theta)\leq \theta$, you will have
$$
LHS\leq b^4 \int_{U(r)}\,\mathrm{d}\sigma(y) = b^4  Area(\left[-\frac1b,\frac1b\right]^2)2\pi r = b^4\left(\frac{4}{b^2}\right)2\pi r=8\pi r\frac{b^3}{b}.
$$
From $b\geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{r}$, it follows that $\frac1b\leq \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$ so above $\leq 8\pi rb^3 \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}.$ Therefore, $C=\frac{8\pi r^2}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: I don't see the first equality. Why the term $Area(\big[-\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{b}\big]^2)$ appears?